# Returning only the values that occured more than a certain date range ago

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, array-formulas, textjoin

I have a spreadsheet where Column A is the year, and column B is the shirt color used. The shirt colors are repeated.

I want to find a way to generate a list of the colors that have not been used in the last 10 years. The problem I am running into is due to the fact that the colors repeat. I tried using

```
=unique(filter(B2:B, A2:A<today()-(365*10)))
```

but shirts that were used in the last 10 years are then still included.

Comment: year is entered as date or as number?

Comment: currently as a date, but I'm flexible with changing it

Comment: posted both....

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, UNIQUE(IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(B:B, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B, A:A>=YEAR(TODAY())-10))))), B:B, ))))
```

[image]

---

for dates in column A use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, UNIQUE(IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(B:B, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B, YEAR(A:A)>=YEAR(TODAY())-10))))), B:B, ))))
```

[image: 10]

Comment: @JosephSchleiss remember to accept the answers that are helpful for you. This way Stack Overflow can better serve other users.